# Constructor Vibrator() is not visible

Tags: android, eclipse, constructor

Im building an Android application in eclipse and i get the error:

> constructor Vibrator() is not visible

I have no clue how to solve this issue can you help?  Here is the section of the code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mVibrator = new Vibrator();
    // Listen for incoming calls to kill the alarm.
    mTelephonyManager =
            (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    mTelephonyManager.listen(
            mPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    AlarmAlertWakeLock.acquireCpuWakeLock(this);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not supposed to create a new Vibrator instance *(therefore the constructor is invisible to you)*, you should rather get an existing one from the system:

```
mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);`